# Query with rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have data in tbl1:

```
item    date    amount
a   1   10
a   2   20
a   3   30
a   4   40
b   1   20
b   2   30
b   3   40
b   4   50
c   1   30
c   2   40
c   3   50
c   4   60
```

But i need like below

```
item    1   2   3   4
a   10  20  30  40
b   20  30  40  50
c   30  40  50  60
```

Comment: With what do you need help? What's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: i dont know how to do, please i need sql query for that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` with conditional aggregation using `CASE` like this.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (item CHAR(1),date int, amount int)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES
('a',   1,   10),
('a',   2,   20),
('a',   3,   30),
('a',   4,   40),
('b',   1,   20),
('b',   2,   30),
('b',   3,   40),
('b',   4,   50),
('c',   1,   30),
('c',   2,   40),
('c',   3,   50),
('c',   4,   60);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
item,
MAX(CASE WHEN date = 1 then amount END) as d1,
MAX(CASE WHEN date = 2 then amount END) as d2,
MAX(CASE WHEN date = 3 then amount END) as d3,
MAX(CASE WHEN date = 4 then amount END) as d4
FROM @tbl1
GROUP BY item
```

**Output**

```
item    d1  d2  d3  d4
a   10  20  30  40
b   20  30  40  50
c   30  40  50  60
```

**Edit**
If you have unknown number of date, then use `dynamic pivot` like this.

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @s  = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),date),'[')  
FROM #tbl1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')

SET @s = N'SELECT item,' + @s + ' FROM #tbl1 PIVOT(MAX(amount) FOR date in(' + @s + ')) as pvt'
print @s
EXEC sp_executeSQL @s
```

Comment: dear sir, there is unknow that how much dates are there.

Comment: Search for dynamic pivot in SO, you'll get many examples for it

Comment: Dear sir,  i want to display in chart with a as x-axix and d1,d2ato dn as y-axis, Please help. in C# windows forms.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PIVOT`

```
SELECT item, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM tbl1 t
PIVOT (SUM(amount) FOR date IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) p
SELECT item, [10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60]
FROM tbl1 t
PIVOT (MAX(date) FOR amount IN ([10], [20], [30], [40], [50], [60])) p
```

OUTPUT:

```
item    1   2   3   4
a       10  20  30  40
b       20  30  40  50
c       30  40  50  60
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f097d/12/0

Comment: dear sir, there is unknow that how much dates are there.

Comment: Then you need to create a dynamic pivot with this

Answer (score 0):

USE `PIVOT`

use pivot concept convert row values as column header

`PIVOT` is one of the New relational operator introduced in Sql Server 2005. It provides an easy mechanism in Sql Server to transform rows into columns.

```
select * from tbl1 pivot(sum(amount) for [date] in([1],[2],[3],[4])) as a
```